# display a calulated value on all post in a category in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, search

i am working on wordpress based coupon site. I have to create a amount calculator which would work on all the individual category pages . I would be having a amount slider which would be having $ values.

Once a value is selected and on clicking the submit button, i want the percentage deals (under that respective category) to calculate a amount with respect to the $ amount selected using the slider. and then displaying it on their respective deals. 
I hope the idea is clear.

Till now, i have managed to, take all the posts title of the current category page into an array, and then using the preg_match feature, i have managed to extract out the '%' deal amount. 
Also i have created a simple slider which the user will need to input their $ amount.

```
<?php
$array = array();
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 1, 'offset' => 0, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);

$title = get_the_title();
array_push($array,$title);

 endforeach; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

  <?php   

foreach($array as $str) {
if(preg_match('/(\d+)\%/i' ,$str,$m)) {
             echo $m[1],"\n"; ?>

  <input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $m[1]; ?>" size=5> 

<?php  }
} ?>
```

the above code is used to fetch all the post under the current category and extracting the % value from the respective post title. The extracted number is in '$m[1]' which i would like to pass against the respective post.

I am not able to define the respective post and passing that '%' amount and in return sending the calculated amount and saving it back to that particular post. that is, on clicking the submit button, i would want that each post having percentage value would get calculated and get displayed against that particular post. Sorry for such a huge explanation. I didnt want any detail to get missed out. Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED CODE - This code is responsible to display a single deal. I have placed the above mentioned in the sidebar file of my theme. I want to display the savings within the respective percentage deal.

```
    <div style="float:left; <?php if($GLOBALS['themename']['display_previewimage'] =="yes"){ ?>width:357px;<?php }else{ ?>width:477px;margin-left:10px;<?php } ?>">

     <h2 class="coupontitle">

        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" <?php if($GLOBALS['premiumpress']['analytics_tracking'] =="yes"){ ?>onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('COUPON CLICK', 'TITLE CLICK', '<?php the_title(); ?>');"<?php } ?> <?php if(is_single()){ ?> target="_blank"<?php } ?>>

           <?php the_title(); ?>

        </a>

    </h2>

    <p><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></p> 

    <?php if($code != "" && $GLOBALS['themename']['system'] =="link"){ ?>        
    </div>
```

Comment: Its a little unclear as to what you are looking for. Correct me if im wrong but you have a category index page that lists posts. In those post titles is a percentage. And on the category index page you have a slider that represents a dollar amount. And this is where i get confused, A user slides the slider to a dollar amount hits submit and what do you want to have happen?

Comment: Hi Chausser, after the user selects the amount and hits the submit button, i want to collect all the % deals from every post and calculate an amount w.r.t to the user input (slider) and display that amount against the respective post.

Comment: So EX: post 1 % is 10% post 2 % is 25% user slides the slider to indicate $100, you want post 1 to show save $10 a post 2 to show save $25?

Comment: yes exactly. right now i am able to fetch '10' from post 1 and '25' from post 2. but i am not able to calculate the value '$10' and '$25' respectively and pass it to the post 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you post the code the renders the post wrapper and where you want the Savings to go and ill give it a shot

Comment: i have edited the question and added the code through which the deals are getting displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have created a JSFIDDLE that will give you an idea about what to do. http://jsfiddle.net/Q5sAK/1/

For this I used the jquery UI slider but this should work for your own slider you just need to call the $.each() function when you are ready.

So we know that your percentage is in the h2 tag with the class coupontitle of all of you products.

First we are going to start by modifying that h2 to have a span tag at the end that we will use to hold the computed savings:

```
<h2 class="coupontitle">
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" <?php if($GLOBALS['premiumpress']['analytics_tracking'] =="yes"){ ?>onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('COUPON CLICK', 'TITLE CLICK', '<?php the_title(); ?>');"<?php } ?> <?php if(is_single()){ ?> target="_blank"<?php } ?>>
       <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
    <span><span>
</h2>
```

Then we need to add the javascript that will calculate the savings.

```
function updateSlider(){
    //Get the value of the slider.
    var curentSliderAmount = $('#sliderId').val();

    //Loop over all of the titles
    $.each($('.coupontitle'),function(index,coupObj){
        //This will create the variable from the regex search that will have all of the parts for the percent we need
        var percent = $(coupObj).text().match(/(\d+)\%/i);
        //We will then take the 2nd part which is just the number without the % sign and make it a percent then multiply that by the slider value and then fix it to a 2 decimal value so it can be used a curency.
        var savings = ((percent[1]*.01) * curentSliderAmount ).toFixed(2);
        //We then set the span html content = to our newly calculated value.
        $('span',coupObj).html('Save: $'+savings);
    });
}
//Run this when the page starts
$(document).ready(function(){ updateSlider() });
```

Then you just need to call updateSlider() when ever the slider updates.

Comment: Thank you so much Chausser. The code works fine for all the percentage deals. Now i want to build a condition for '$' deals and deals which dont have any amount in it.

Comment: any percent amount? So posts that have no saving % just show the input value?

Comment: means, deals that does not have 25% or any amount in it. Some of the deals have '$20' Off and some of the deals dont have any numbers in it. Also, the given code, only works for the first deal, may be it is breaking because the other deals are not % off deals.

Comment: I have added multiple conditions for all $ Off deals and Shipping deals and it works fine. I was trying to separate out the input and output using a Submit button. Means i would like to slide the slider and select a amount. and on clicking the submit button i want all the calculations to take place and display the result.

Comment: In that case i would recommend that you instead use the wordpress custom field options for posts and set like a savings type and a savings amount then use "data-" attributes on the title to determine what type of savings if any that post has then calculate it and display it.

Comment: I have implemented savings for different types of deals separately and it is working fine. I was just trying to use a 'onclick' function to display the calculated value. First i want the user to slide for the desired amount, and on clicking the submit button. i want the page to refresh and then display the values besides every deal.

Comment: Hey, I somehow figured it out. Thanks a lot for your help.